How to read a big endian varint in go?
I was writing a sqlite db file reader in go, and per the specification the sql creators make heavy usage of varints.
I started by using the encoding/binary package to read these varints but it doesn't seem like they have a function that fits this use case.
The binary.Read() third parameter expects the address of where the data will be stored and it will read a certain amount of bytes based on the what was passed in. For example, if you pass in a uint16 it will read 2 bytes. However, being that I'm trying to read an integer of variable length, I don't know ahead of time how many bytes it's supposed to read (in some cases you do know but not always).
The binary.ReadUvarint() and binary.Uvarint() seems better suited for this use case, but they read the bytes in little endian format, but I need them to be read in big endian format.
You can try it out by attempting to read the []byte{0x82, 0x29} and it should return 297.
I ended up writing the following functions:
// Big-endian
func parseVarInt(buf []byte) (uint64, int) {
    result := uint64(0)
    for i, b := range buf {
        result = (result << 7) | uint64(b&0x7f)
        if b&0x80 == 0 {
            return result, i + 1
        }
    }
    return result, 0
}

func bytesToInt(bytes []byte) uint64 {
    var result uint64
    for _, b := range bytes {
        result = (result << 8) | uint64(b)
    }
    return result
}

My question is, are there any functions in the standard library that behave like this and I just missed it or is this just a very specific use case?

It's a little bit difficult to understand what exactly you're asking (because it seems like most of the question is redundant), but I think you're asking if there's a big-endian varint decoder in the standard library. I think there isn't. You can write your own, copying the standard library implementation of the little-endian varint decoder. Your implementation looks ok, but doesn't validate (which may or may not be relevant to your use-case).

Using io.ByteReader (like the standard library) makes more sense than using []byte because you need to somehow track which bytes have been read, which is variable if you're reading a varint.

(I expect you can find a pure-go implementation of a sqlite db reader, which may suit your needs without you writing your own).

@PaulHankin That is what the question boils down to. Is there a big-endian varint decoder in standard lib. All the functions that were using the first function only had access to the byte buffer so that's why I used that, and the function returns how many bytes were read, so I can keep track of the offset

@PaulHankin I'm sure there's a better implementation out there for sure. But I just wanted to learn how it all works under the hood, it's not going out to production or anything.

@estevao, why doesn't math/big's Int type and its SetBytes(buf) function work?  And, did you come up with both parseVarInt and bytesToInt? They seem to give very different results for [0x82 0x29]. Thanks.

@ZachYoung I wasn't look to use big numbers, but rather to decode numbers when reading the file. I wrote those two functions on the fly based on the descriptions from the  sqlite specs. Yes, the functions work differently. Varints are used through out the file for various different purposes as they make small int64 take about just 1 or 2 bytes. The second function is used for record headers which give an int without the preceeding zeroes. So, they should give different results as they 'encode' the integer differently.
